# How to re-create indexes in elasticseach

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-dynamodb

I am working a project which is developed using AWS serverless, DB is dynamo and elastic search, for the front end react and nodeJS for backend. It was developed by some other group of developers and now I m being part of it without any KT on it. I managed to get the project up and running. Until now the journey.

There was something called re-indexing of data at elasticsearch which should happen at the end of every month for this project. As I m new to these things I did some mistake and the indexes are somehow corrupted it seems. I m commenting like that because, I m getting the data for the same query on the last month index, but no data on the recent index which was created for the current month.

I can not use the old index as, there was some additional data created on top of that index and I should get the complete data now.

So I m planning to recreate the indexes to make sure, i have all the data in the new indexes including latest records created recently.

Can someone help me in understanding how can I do this.
I have came across lot of help docs and tutorials on net, but nothing like what I m looking for.
I m extremely sorry if this is a duplicate of some other question. May be due to the unfamiliarity of these technologies, my jargons are not matching with what I should write here and get the help for.

Let me know if some other information is required here.

Comment: please add the command you used to reindex and the command you used to query the new index created.

Comment: Not sure if I m giving you the complete details, but I was instructed to execute below 2 queries to reindex things 1) For creating new index "PUT prod.<tenant>.historical.actions-<year>-<month>", which i guess doesnt contain any data yet 2) For mapping data "PUT prod.<tenant>.historical.tasks-2020-12/_alias/api.stage.<tenant>.today.tasks
{
  "filter": { 
    "term": {
      "snapshotDate": "2020-12-03"
    }
  }
}"  where I guess, the data from the snapshot dated "2020-12-03" is being copied to new index got created in the first step.

Comment: Want to know, only just for fetching complete data, are you wanting to reindex? In such case, querying(search) from both previous & current index ( searching multiple indices), wouldn't it help you? Pls update story with requests you are trying & expected results for better answers

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to understand what you exactly want, however if you want to make a copy of your existing index, you can do it by:

1. [Create index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html):
   Use any upfront mappings if required.

```
    PUT <destination_index_name>
```

2. Copy the data ([re-index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html) operation):

```
    POST _reindex
    {
      "source": {
        "index": "source_index_name"
      },
      "dest": {
        "index": "destination_index_name"
      }
    }
```

Comment: From what I understand, this ain't what @Sunil is looking for

Comment: In simple I have created (Not me actually, but one of my team members) an index from existing index. Unfortunately I dont see all the data that is there in the source index at the newly created index. What could be the reason for that? Whatever may be teh reason, if I redo the same exercise in proper way will I be able to get all the data that is there in the source index? For doing the same what commands or queries I need to execute at Kibana console to achieve the it? We dont know any other ways of executing those queries apart from Kibana console. I m just days old in this technology.

Comment: By the way @Ankit I have tried your suggestion and getting errors for all of the documents. "cause" : {
        "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason" : "failed to parse field [createdDate] of type [long] in document with id '20210305_b3120b67-778c-490e-a763-e790a5843912'. Preview of field's value: '2020-05-18T11:42:01.599Z'",
        "caused_by" : {
          "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
          "reason" : "For input string: \"2020-05-18T11:42:01.599Z\""
        }
      }

Comment: Hello @SunilYerra, you are getting "mapper_parsing_exception" this means that the mapping for the destination index is not defined properly. Can you try use the correct mappings and see if it works? You can use "GET /index-mappings/_mapping" to see the mappings of older index that you are trying to copy.